# Best film and shutter speed for Mansfield Skylark

Tags: film, iso, shutter-speed, rangefinder

My daughter picked up an old [Mansfield Skylark](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Mansfield_Skylark) camera at a yard sale.  Can anyone recommend a film type/speed and shutter speed for overcast daylight conditions?  The shutter speeds are simply 'B' which I guess stands for 'bulb' and 2 through 6, 6 being the fastest.  Any advice or hints would be great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started out in the 80s with a similar rangefinder by Olympus and regularly got great results with Kodak's black and white Tri-X. Now available as 400TX this is a fast yet fine grained film that can handle push-processing well. It captures nice high contrast which will help bring the best out of overcast conditions.

An old rule of thumb you can start with in choosing exposures is based on full sunlight: f16 at 1/film-speed. So in this case you would use use f16 at 1/400th second, which I am guessing may correspond closest to the "6" value (fastest shutter on these cameras was 1/500th or "6"). So, to open up a couple of stops for the overcast light, get the sweet-spot of the lens, and a mildly shallow depth-of-field - you should try F8 at shutter speed "6" with Tri-X.

I suspect that will work a treat.